# XCode 9.0: Error Domain=PlugInKit Code=13 "query cancelled" error AFTER permissions allowed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, info.plist

I have been getting this error when running my app on simulator after updating Xcode. I looked at other SO questions related to this error, and they all had to do with permissions. But even after including code to ask permissions, and making sure `Photo Library Usage` is in my `Info.plist`, I still get the error.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{


    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    [PHPhotoLibrary requestAuthorization:^(PHAuthorizationStatus status) {
        switch (status) {
            case PHAuthorizationStatusAuthorized:
                NSLog(@"PHAuthorizationStatusAuthorized");
                ipc = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
                ipc.delegate = self;
                if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
                {
                    ipc.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
                    ipc.showsCameraControls = NO;
                    ipc.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = YES;
                    ipc.allowsEditing = NO;

                    [self addChildViewController:ipc];
                    [self.view addSubview:ipc.view];
                    [ipc didMoveToParentViewController:self];

                }else{
                    ipc.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
                    //launch image picker view controller
                    ipc.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
                    [self presentViewController:ipc animated:YES completion:nil];

                }
                break;
            case PHAuthorizationStatusDenied:
                NSLog(@"PHAuthorizationStatusDenied");
                break;
            case PHAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined:
                NSLog(@"PHAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined");
                break;
            case PHAuthorizationStatusRestricted:
                NSLog(@"PHAuthorizationStatusRestricted");
                break;
        }
    }];
}
```

When I click on the tab for this view, I just have the IPC view controller for LibraryControlSource slides up the screen and then back down (as if being dismissed) nonstop. Each time it slides up, I get the `Error Domain=PlugInKit Code=13 "query cancelled"` error in the console.